# Function whose argument is an unsigned 32 bit integer

Tags: ocaml

in ocaml I am trying to write a function which takes as an argument a 32 bit unsigned integer. However I am having problems determining the correct identifier to use in the type declaration of the function. By googling I could only find int32. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Int32](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int32.html) models *signed* 32-bit arithmetic. If you're only planning to pass such values around (for example to communicate them to a C API), or use operations that don't depend on signedness, such as `add`, `mul`, `sub`, you can use `Int32` just fine. Division and modulo are implemented differently on signed and unsigned numbers, so you shouldn't use those of the Int32 module.

(There was a [previous caml-list discussion](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2004/07/f1c483068cc62075c916f7ad7d640ce0.fr.html) on this topic.)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I had a look at the caml-list discussion. It mentions only division and modulus is a problem, but I presume that modulo is also a problem?

Comment: When I say "modulus" I actually mean "modulo". Sorry if it was not the right english word. I will edit my answer for clarity.

Comment: In the caml-list they were also referring to "modulus", so maybe there is a problem with modulus as well?

Comment: Another case where the difference may matter is when converting between types.  If you convert `Int32.t` to `int` on a 64 bit system, for example, there is no direct way to treat the `Int32.t` value as unsigned.

Comment: Since when does `mul` not depend on signedness?!

Answer (score 7):

Adding to gasche's answer there is a library that provides a module with uint32 type and corresponding operations (including division) - [ocaml-uint](https://github.com/andrenth/ocaml-uint).

Comment: For future readers, that library has been continued on in https://github.com/andrenth/ocaml-stdint